# c# visual studio 2017 publish error

Tags: c#

After installing report viewer and used it .. When i publish it.. it gives me this error when i run the installer .. i dont know if report viewer cause it tnx for helping me

> PLATFORM VERSION INFO
>       Windows             : 10.0.15063.0 (Win32NT)
>       Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
>       System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.2046.0 built by: NET47REL1
>       clr.dll             : 4.7.2098.0 built by: NET47REL1LAST
>       dfdll.dll           : 4.7.2046.0 built by: NET47REL1
>       dfshim.dll          : 10.0.15063.0 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
>
> SOURCES
>       Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/jeric/Desktop/Patient%20installer/WindowsFormsApp2.application
>
> IDENTITIES
>       Deployment Identity     : WindowsFormsApp2.application, Version=1.0.0.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=27c89c7a35419cf0, processorArchitecture=msil
>
> APPLICATION SUMMARY
>       * Installable application.
>
> ERROR SUMMARY
>       Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
>       * Activation of C:\Users\jeric\Desktop\Patient installer\WindowsFormsApp2.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>           + Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Users/jeric/Desktop/Patient%20installer/Application%20Files/WindowsFormsApp2_1_0_0_8/WindowsFormsApp2.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
>           + Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
>               -HRESULT:   0x80070c81
>                Start line:    0
>                Start column:  0
>                Host file:
>           + Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070C81
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
>       No transaction error was detected.
>
> WARNINGS
>       There were no warnings during this operation.
>
> OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
>       * [7/3/2017 6:13:29 AM] : Activation of C:\Users\jeric\Desktop\Patient installer\WindowsFormsApp2.application has started.
>       * [7/3/2017 6:13:29 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
>       * [7/3/2017 6:13:29 AM] : Installation of the application has started.
>
> ERROR DETAILS
>       Following errors were detected during this operation.
>       * [7/3/2017 6:13:29 AM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
>           - Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Users/jeric/Desktop/Patient%20installer/Application%20Files/WindowsFormsApp2_1_0_0_8/WindowsFormsApp2.exe.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
>           - Source: System.Deployment
>           - Stack trace:
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>               at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
>           --- Inner Exception ---
>           System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
>           - Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed: 
>               -HRESULT:   0x80070c81
>                Start line:    0
>                Start column:  0
>                Host file:
>           - Source: System.Deployment
>           - Stack trace:
>               at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(FileStream fileStream)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
>           --- Inner Exception ---
>           System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>           - Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070C81
>           - Source: System.Deployment
>           - Stack trace:
>               at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateCMSFromXml(Byte[] buffer, UInt32 bufferSize, IManifestParseErrorCallback Callback, Guid& riid)
>               at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
>
> COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
>       No transaction information is available.

Comment: Wow, that's a really long error message. What kind of "publish" are you trying to do?

Comment: for installer .. i just click that on build section

Answer (score -1):

Under "Project Properties > Publish > Application Files" I set all non-EN versions of the referenced files to Exclude, re-published and now the application deploys correctly.

[exclude option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADmqC.png)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply i jut exclude the .dll that contains the zh